# Dart Flutter: How to compare int values of a Map?

Tags: flutter, sorting, dictionary, dart

Say that I have a `Map<String, int>` containing entries and I would like to select the first entry with the highest value, see the example below:

```
Map<String, int> wordCount = {
'foo' : 3,
'bar' : 3,
'john' : 4,
'doe' : 3,
'four' : 4
}
```

What is the most efficient way to get `john` as it has the first highest value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
void main() {
  Map<String, int> wordCount = {
    'foo': 3,
    'bar': 3,
    'john': 4,
    'doe': 3,
    'four': 4
  };

  final nameWithHighestValue =
      wordCount.entries.reduce((a, b) => a.value >= b.value ? a : b).key;

  print(nameWithHighestValue); // john
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```dart
print(wordCount.entries.reduce((maxEntry, entry) { 
    return maxEntry.value < entry.value ? entry : maxEntry
}).key);
```

Comment: Thank you for the time and answer.